# Like button for Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is possible to add on a website a like button where user likes a specific Facebook Page? Or this action is only possible when the user accesses my Facebook Page?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

You can specify the page you want people to like, the size, everything.

You can also make a page plugin, which allow your users to like a Facebook page, see who likes it, etc :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin